# Mixed content error on my website after redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: php, html, https, xmlhttprequest, oscommerce

Recently I have included an SSL certificate for HTTPS redirection for my lightweight e-commerce [site](https://voberhaat.com/). The site is built with an OSCommerce platform and what I need help with is fixing these kinds of errors (on console) appearing throughout the pages: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://voberhaat.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://voberhaat.com/oc-content/themes/bender/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

The layout and design of the site are broken after the HTTPS redirection and I am trying to find the files where I can rewrite the HTTPS for the relevant contents it is asking for. In my server if I navigate to the corresponding paths and files, I can't figure out the URL, they don't simply exist there.
Someone could help me out regarding this?

Comment: anywhere where you used a specific `http://` on any links/css/etc etc will cause this. Remove the unnecessary `http://` from all links

Comment: RiggsFolly, thanks for your quick comment. There are lots of directories and files. The site is using theme and it is built on platform rather than coding from scratch. Therefore it is very difficult to find the files where the http:// is used only. Do you habe any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forcing https for your entire site via an .htaccess file?

Try creating an .htaccess file in your main directory and add this code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The code is already added inside .htaccess, otherwise the HTTPS wouldn't redirect.

Answer (score 0):

First: edit your includes/configure.php
set

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://<yoursite>');
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://<yoursite>');
define('ENABLE_SSL', true);
```

Second:
Check header.php, footer.php, breadcrumbs.php for "http:" links